Как увеличить продолжительность взаимодействия в disnake?
У меня в музыкальном боте при проигрывании треков через 15 минут пропадает взаимодействие(P.S:Обычно на 6 треке глохнет). Хотелось бы узнать существуют ли методы увеличения продолжительности взаимодействия?
